# scrollTop not working in Safari

Tags: jquery, safari, scrolltop

Firs time this is happening to me, i'm aware that scrollTop have some issues with some browsers but this time is only in Safari, Firefox and Chrome are ok.
Here is my code

```
$(window).scroll(function()
{
    var s = $('html, body').scrollTop();
    console.log(s) //ok on FF and Chrome, but Safari returns 0
}
```

Comment: is this your only code or there is last `)` after `}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly you must check for both the `<html>` and `<body>` element separately.

```
$(window).scroll(function()
{
    var s = $('html').scrollTop() || $('body').scrollTop();
    console.log(s);
});
```

Comment: I tried to make it work inside iframe for a wrapper element but it didn't work in iOS safari , any suggestion?
`$("#wrapper").scrollTop(100);  //it doesn't scroll top upto the "wrapper" element`

Answer (score 1):

You can use also:

> document.scrollingElement

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document/scrollingElement